How can I solve $\int \frac{1}{(a^2+x^2)\sqrt{b^2+x^2}}dx$?
I have been struggling with this integral,
$$ \int \frac{dx}{(a^2+x^2)\sqrt{b^2+x^2}}$$
I thought, I only want an $a$ or a $b$ in there, not both. I multiplied top and bottom by $\sqrt{b^2+x^2}$, factored out the radical, and expanded in partial fractions,
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{b^2+x^2}}{b^2-a^2}\left(\frac{1}{a^2+x^2} - \frac{1}{b^2+x^2}\right)dx
= \frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\left( \int\frac{\sqrt{b^2+x^2}}{a^2+x^2}dx + \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+x^2}}dx \right)$$
So at least the integral on the right is something I can do with a trig substitution. But when I tried the same trick on the left one, hoping it would shake out in the end, I wound up with
$$\frac{1}{a^2}\int\sqrt{(b^2-a^2) + \sec^2(u)}du$$
And there I stay. That looks dishearteningly similar to an elliptic integral. Is there a way forward?

Substitute $y=x/\sqrt{x^2+b^2}$.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4612212/686284

Hint Substitute $$y = \frac{x}{\sqrt{b^2 + x^2}}$$ to transform the integral to rationalize the integral;
$$\int \frac{dy}{(b^2 - a^2) y^2 + a^2} .$$
(One way you might guess this substitution is to apply the standard hyperbolic substitution $x = b \sinh t$, which transforms the integral to $\int \frac{dt}{a \sinh^2 t + b^2}$—and in particular eliminates the radical—and then substitute $y = \tanh t$. Composing these substitutions gives the one in the hint.)
From here, the form of the solution depends on the sign of the coefficient $b^2 - a^2$.

Wow, it's like you had that right at the tip of your brain! To be honest, I didn't even consider the hyperbolics. I guess I just haven't gotten very familiar with them.

If you do integration often, they're definitely worth having in your toolbox.

WLOG, let’s assume that $a,b>0$.
Let $x=b\sinh \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{1}{\left(a^2+b^2 \sinh ^2 \theta\right) b \cosh \theta} \cdot b \cosh \theta d \theta \\
& =\int \frac{d \theta}{a^2+b^2 \sinh ^2 \theta} \\
& =\int \frac{\operatorname{sech}^2 \theta}{a^2 \operatorname{sech}^2 \theta+b^2 \tanh ^2 \theta} d \theta \\
& =\int \frac{d t}{(b^2-a^2) t^2+ a^2}, \text { where } t=\tanh \theta (= \frac{x}{\sqrt{b^2+x^2}})\\
&= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{a \sqrt{b^2-a^2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t \sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{a}\right)+C & \text { if } b>a \\ \frac{t}{a^2}+C & \text { if } a=b \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{t \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}\right)+C & \text { if } a>b\end{cases}\\ &=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{a \sqrt{b^2-a^2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x \sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{a \sqrt{b^2+x^2}}\right)+C & \text { if } b>a \\ \frac{x}{a^2 \sqrt{b^2+x^2}}+C & \text { if } a=b  \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a \sqrt{b^2+x^2}}\right)+C & \text { if } a>b\end{cases}\end{aligned}
$$
